# Need to create index for column containing JSON/XML string. How to analysis in cassandra using jsonTokenizerFactory in solr

Tags: json, solr, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

I'm new in cassandra, I'm using DSE 4.1.3 and I will get JSON documents/files as feed and I have to Store it in one of the Cassandra table column as a json string and I have to perform analysis on it. Can anyone tell me how I can create indexing DSE-Search (solr) using jsonTonkenFactory class.

Recently I come to know about SIREn plugins API extention to solr. SIREn provide example to make indexing on JSON document

```
 <fieldType name="json" class="org.sindice.siren.solr.schema.SirenField"
           omitNorms="true"
           datatypeConfig="datatypes.xml">

  <analyzer type="index">

    <tokenizer class="org.sindice.siren.solr.analysis.JsonTokenizerFactory"/>

  </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

and Fields

```
    <schema name="example" version="1.5">

 <fields>

 <!-- _version_ and update log are required for SolrCloud -->
 <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

 <!-- The ID of the document -->
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<!-- json indexing scheme -->
<field name="json" type="json" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

 </fields>
```

I tried to do it, by placing SIREn plugin Jar files in with Solr jar files /etc/share/dse/solr/

For more information:
http://sirendb.com/docs/getting-started/

Can anybody have any idea what and how to do it in this kind of scenario ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the doc for where to place custom jars for Solr:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchConfLibPath.html

Packaged installs: /usr/share/dse

Binary installs: install_location/resources/dse/lib

Comment: SIREn Plugin API will not work with DSE as DSE doesn't support schemaless mode in Solr. And SIREn is a schemaless structured document search system that combines free text search with structured search over arbitrary json data. The system is an extension of Lucene/Solr, the world’s leading search engine technology.